# Starting point for a simple game written in action script

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to develop a simple game like: http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/games/falldown2
And then making it a bit more fancy. But I don't know where to start. I have already started AS3 so I know about the syntax and stuff, but I am kinda lost. Does anyone knows of a nice starting point or a tutorial that can help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4592/as3-flash-game-dev-looking-for-good-current-step-by-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though ilollar is right about the thing he says, it can be a lot to handle when you're starting out!

I'd like to point at [Michael James Williams avoider tutorial](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/09/17/avoider-game-tutorial-1/), it's a really great resource for starting to learn AS3 and game development! After you have made some stuff, you can always get into design patterns and MVC. But this is a really great place to start. Here's his own introduction:

> This tutorial has been read by
>   thousands of people. It’s been used as
>   teaching aids in schools, colleges and
>   universities, it’s been translated
>   into Spanish, Polish, and Italian, and
>   it’s even been used as the basis for
>   some commercial games. By the time
>   you’ve finished all twelve parts,
>   you’ll have a good foundation in
>   programming Flash. [Click here to get
>   started](http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/09/17/avoider-game-tutorial-1/).

Answer (score 1):

Besides obvious answers like "Go get a book" or "Go to a AS3 game dev forum" (both of which should definitely be done), here's a couple of "kicking off points" to help guide your research.

First, get a good understanding of design patterns.  Development can get messy, and game development even more so.  Keeping your code well structured and organized is essential.  Following good design patterns will help enormously with that.  Learn about developing with MVC (Model-View-Controller) in mind, which will help you keep your data (model) separate from your views (what you see).  This organization will help you not get a bunch of ugly entangled spaghetti code that becomes too difficult to read or decipher.  Additionally, getting a good understanding of the Command Pattern can be very useful for game development, since you can set up commands that are fired in response to user-interaction.

Next, take a look into the theory of game development.  This is a humongous topic, so it isn't something I can effectively summarize here, but in general, do some research in the game event-loop.  This is the loop that fires at regular intervals and tells your game to do calculations and drawing to the stage.  Though highly debatable, it is common practice to separate your math calculations and drawing into two separate loops.  In AS3, there's good arguments to have your calculations fire on a Timer-based loop and have your drawing be based on an Event.ENTER_FRAME loop.

Lastly, never underestimate how helpful looking at samples can be.  There's a ton of AS3 game dev sources online, so it should be pretty easy to find some samples to learn from.

Oh, and have fun!  Game development can be frustrating, but as long as you keep having fun you'll come back for more.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good book on Flash Game Development.

[Real-World Flash Game Development: How to Follow Best Practices AND Keep Your Sanity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/024081178X)

A friend of mine wrote it and he's been building Flash based games for like 7 years.

I learned Flash / AS3 development many years ago using this book:

[Foundation Actionscript 3.0 Animation: Making Things Move!](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002FQKB2E)